# Convert native byte...?

Tags: c++-cli

How can I convert a native byte (unsigned char) type variable to a managed byte array which is array^ in C++?

```
byte sData[255]; // convert to System::Byte array or copy content to byteArray?? How?

array<System::Byte>^ byteArray;
```

Thankyou for your assiastance...

Comment: This is not [tag:C++], it is [tag:c++-cli] or something.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
char buf[] = "Native String";
int len = strlen(buf);
array<Byte> ^byteArray = gcnew array<Byte>(len + 2);
Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)buf, byteArray, 0, len );
```

You can find some more info in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26d6hf4z.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = Mat.total() * Mat.elemSize();
byte * bytes = new byte[size];
std::memcpy(bytes, Mat.data, size * sizeof(byte));

// convert native byte array to managed Byte array
array<Byte> ^byteArray = gcnew array<Byte>(size + 2);
Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)bytes, byteArray, 0, size);
```